# Is it acceptable to say "fed up OF" - surely it should be "fed up WITH" or "bored WITH something" rather than "bored OF something"?

Tags: grammar, prepositions, phrase-usage

I hear people using *of* when I have always thought it was *with* in the circumstances explained above.  It seems to be getting more common.

Comment: There is nothing grammatically unpleasant about *fed up of* and *bored of* to prevent their becoming common idiomatic phrases, however I don't think I've ever heard the former, and the later only rarely.

Comment: Is this possibly related to the merger of /v/ and /ð/ in some English dialects? Once these are merged, *fed up with* and *fed up of* sound nearly the same (/fɛdupwəv/ and /fɛdupəv/).

Comment: http://www.macmillandictionaryblog.com/bored-of-life

Comment: *fed up of* sounds wrong to me.  It’s definitely *with* in my book. Perhaps they sound the same in some dialects and that’s fine by me as long as I can hear *with* even if they say *of*. Otherwise I’ll file away their faux pas in the same place I file *then* for *than* and other trivial errors.  *bored* is different and can take either *with* or *of* as well as *by* and possibly others as well.

Comment: I started noticing _bored of_ in the 1980's, and at first it struck me as a mistake. However, I soon heard it in quite wide use. The truth is that language changes, and if people start using a new form, then that becomes part of the language

Answer (score 5):

Oxford Dictionary says:

> Do you ever get bored with eating out all the time?
>
> Delegates were bored by the lectures.
>
> He grew bored of his day job.
>
> The first two constructions, bored with and bored by, are the standard
>   ones. The third, bored of, is more recent than the other two and it’s
>   become extremely common. In fact, the Oxford English Corpus contains
>   almost twice as many instances of bored of than bored by. It
>   represents a perfectly logical development of the language, and was
>   probably formed on the pattern of expressions such as tired of or
>   weary of. Nevertheless, some people dislike it and it’s not fully
>   accepted in standard English. It’s best to avoid using it in formal
>   writing.

So there's nothing wrong or unusual with **bored of**.

Answer (score 2):

My personal favorite is "different than."

No, it's **fed up *with*** and **bored *with***.

And, of course, **have had enough *of***, **tired *of***.

Comment: Very new to this interesting site so have managed to post question twice.   Thank you for your reply, would like to know why it is so commonly misused.

Comment: @Bopamamie: It is commonly misused because we live in an epoch of aggressive anti-intellectualism, when the illiterates are conditioned to think that pointing things out to them is the same as judging them. Incidentally, if you like the answer, you might as well upvote it. There are two arrows to the left of the answer: the one pointing upward is for upvoting.

Comment: In fairness to the 'illiterates' why are we tired of but bored with?

Comment: @Bopamamie: For the same reason we are delighted by (or with). Language is a synthesis of auditory impressions and visual images: combinations need to sound good and form just the right kind of mental pictures. In music, the combination of the tonic and fifth sounds good, but try the tonic and second, and you'll get a dissonance. Why? That's how God made us.